# How to return all rows of the table in Adonis JS using the foreign key?

Tags: node.js

Good afternoon everyone!

I am developing an application and I don't know how to return all rows in the table segmented by the `user_id` (FK) of my table.

I did the following:

```
class LojaController {

     async index({ auth }) {
         const lojas = await Loja.findByOrFail('user_id', auth.user.id);

         return lojas;
  }

}
```

However, it only returns the first line that contains the informed `user_id`. I need all the lines to be returned.

Anyone who can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: SO is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site, and translate your question (including title!) into English, or else post it on the [Portuguese Stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I translated the question. I'm sorry for the mistake.